# Limit the user data accessed by Facebook Login

Tags: facebook-apps

I'm adding Facebook Login to my website. When users log into my application they have to accept a Facebook popup saying "Muzi.ch would like to access your public profile, friend list and email address."

I only need email to manage users in my database. Is it possible to "configure" Facebook Login in my app to not ask for "friend list" or other details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Facebook, your public profile and friend list are always public - and so accessible by any app.

The login dialog spells this out to the end user, but there's no way to *not* ask for this information.

The docs confirm this [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/).